# Delete file contents after line == "xxxxxxx"

Tags: linux, bash

I have a bunch of files I need to clean. I need to delete all lines below a line that is equal to something (that line should be removed too).

How can I do that in bash?

I just need the example of how to delete the lines, I can loop all the files myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest to just tell sed to quit when it sees it.

```
sed -n '/xxxxxxx/q;p' input.txt
```

Comment: You could also do this with `sed '/xxxxxx/Q'` (slightly shorter).  Also, don't forget to anchor the expression and to supply `-i` to sed so that the file actually gets modified, instead of just displayed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Perl:

```
perl -i.bak -pe 'exit if /xxxxxxx/' filename.txt ...
```

This will replace files in place.

Comment: But I asked how to do it in bash.

Comment: bash itself is not suitable for this type of operation. Use the correct tool for the job.

Comment: Why not .net or java? Seriously, for cutting a text file in the middle is it really perl that can do the job? sed or awk is perfectly suited for the job and those came with all linux distro, while perl is not.

Comment: @Meredith: `sed` and `awk` are no more Bash than Perl is. If you really want to do it in Bash: `while read -r line; do [[ $line == xxxxxxx ]] && break; echo "$line"; done < inputfile`

Answer (score 0):

'sed' is the easiest way to do this but if you have a bit more complex requirement
You can also use 'awk'.

For this particular case, create a file 'foo.awk' with following content:

```
{
    if ($0 == "xxxxxx")
            exit
    else
            print $0
}
```

and from shell invoke the following command:

```
awk -f foo.awk $FILE_NAME
```