# Delete contents of file before XXXXXX

Tags: python, bash

My question is very similar to [Delete file contents after line == "xxxxxxx"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4560875/delete-file-contents-after-line-xxxxxxx) but instead of deleting the part after the term XXXXXX, I want to delete the content BEFORE.

In SO Spirit, let me put forward my attempt :

I do this in Python by:

```
f = open('paper.html')
lines=f.readlines()
for it in range(1,len(lines)):
 if 'Visible' in lines[it]:
  counter=it
  break

h = open('paper_sub.html','wa')
for it in range(counter+1,len(lines)):
 h.write(lines[it])

f.close()
h.close()
```

Is there a sed way of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed -n '/.*Visible.*/,$p' originalfile > newfile
```

If you don't want the line with Visible

```
sed '1,/.*Visible.*/d' originalfile > newfile
```